# Does Naruto use Flying Raijin Jutsu?

Tags: naruto

[This](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Flying_Thunder_God_Technique) technique is used by Minato Namikaze, but does Naruto use it as well? As far as I remember, he dodged a punch from Raikage who said that he has surpassed his father.

Is this technique something else?

Comment: I have not found any mention of him having used the technique in question.

Comment: So, it's a no, right.

Comment: :) I didn't post it as an answer because, to be frank, I'm not an expert. I just did a few quick Google searches and all I found were fanfiction references.

Comment: Oh, it's ok. I just hope that someone like [MadaraUchiha](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/11495/madara-uchiha) answers it :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Naruto does not use the Flying Thunder God technique at any point in the series.

Notable similarities:

- Gaining partial mastery over Kurama got him fast enough to be on par with the Third Raikage, who was said to be the fastest shinobi alive (Second only to Minato, when he was alive)
- Gaining full mastery over Kurama (and becoming friends with him) increased his speed even further, shown to be able to nearly instantly create a shadow clone and fly to the other side of the battlefield to stop two simultaneous attacks on his friends.

> - During his time as Hokage we've seen him use the Body Flicker technique, which is a rather general name for "moving really really faster so that it looks like teleportation", but the distinction between Body Flicker and Flying Thunder God was made several times in the series.

To summerize: Naruto is very fast, however, he cannot use the Flying Thunder God technique.

Comment: I dont think its mastery over Kurama. Its just he used Body Flicker technique without realising. This would be similar to the one Shisui used which is almost as fast as FTG but doesn't have the flaw of marking the destination.

Answer (score 2):

I think Naruto may have some knowledge of the Flying Thunder God technique, but has never showcased it in live combat. However referring back to the scene where Naruto dodges the Raikage's punch; Naruto does not use the 'FTG' technique but instead uses his brute speed, in the nine tails chakra mode, to match that of the speed of the 'FTG' technique. 
On an important note it is crucial to remember that, after Naruto received the Six Paths Sage Power and entered the Six Paths Sage mode; his speed has enhanced immensely when compared to that of the Nine tails chakra mode. So the question is not whether Naruto knows the 'FTG' technique, but  whether is it really necessary for Naruto? as he has already surpassed the speed of the 'FTG' technique using his acquired powers.

Answer (score 1):

He used it in the movies, im not sure if that's canon or not.

Comment: They seem to be looking for a comic reference. However is there any chance you could mention which movies he used it in and when, to narrow down the source a little?

Answer (score 1):

The movie was Road to Ninja, where Naruto and Sakura where trapped in a tskyuomi. Even Obito says "The last time I got hit by that Jutsu was 16 years ago."[image] referring to when Minato used Rasengan combined with Flying Thunder God and hit Obito/Menma on the back before he could dematerialize that part of his body using close range Kamui.[image]
The scene I am talking about occurs about 14 minutes or so before the end of the movie.
Not sure if it's Canon or not, I would assume it is since the plot of the movie was Obito wanting to test out a limited version of the Infinite Tsukuyomi which would have some relevance to the storyline.

Comment: This looks like a comment on the existing answers, rather than an answer in its own right.

Comment: It is, it just wouldn't let me comment on other people's posts because I don't have the "privilege". Anyway, it's in response to the comment down below on the post that Michael Bailey posted, specifically in reply to the comment that Edlothiad posted.

Comment: i have removed the link you posted as it is my belief that the site is an illegal streaming service which has not paid for any licenses to stream the content it has on there. i suspect this because it doesn't host anything but rather get links from sites like MP4Upload and Streamango. this tactic is used by many illegal sites to try and pawn off responsibility (which will fail in a European Court)

Comment: (cont.) also looking at some of the filenames of videos that do work (the one you posted didn't) you have names like *"[MA]FullMetal.Alchemist.Brotherhood.-.01.[1080p.BluRay.x264].[10bit].[DHD] [720p].mp4.mp4"* which i have seen with copies downloaded illegally from torrent sites, for instance *[1080p.BluRay.x264]* means it's 1080p Bluray Rip assuming using H264 Compression

Answer (score 1):

In chapter 700 of the manga, the final chapter which takes place years after the events of the series, an adult Hokage Naruto uses Flying Raijin to stop his son, Boruto, from vandalizing the Hokage monument.

Naruto does not use the technique during the War, and in fact had never seen it until encountering the resurrected Minato at the end.

Answer (score 1):

He uses Flying Raijin 2 times: against Menma in the movie and to stop Boruto from vandalizing the Great Stone Faces.

Note- He shares his and Kurama's chakra with his reanimated father to teleport the entire allied shinobi forces out of the barrier erected by Obito Uchiha during the Fourth Great Ninja War

Answer (score 0):

1. used on Kisame right after achieving Kurama chakra form for the first time inside the sealing cave (referred to by Bee as Teleportation technique and seeing a yellow flash)
2. used in the very last chapter of Naruto to stop Boruto from painting in the stone mural (Borito calls out the name of the technique)
3. used in the movie "road to ninja" against Obito (referred to as the same Technique Minato hit him with 16 years ago)

So, yes. Naruto knows that Jutsu and uses it. But very rarely. Reason probably being that he just learnt it during the Ninja war and still had trouble with controlling it and incorporating it into his fighting style seamlessly.

Answer (score -2):

Naruto is shown using Flying Raijin Or Flying Thunder God Technique in one of Naruto Shippuden Movies Against Menma

Comment: This answer would benefit from a specific source instead of "one of the movies".

Answer (score -2):

I think he did use it once to stop Boruto from vandalizing the Hokages's faces.

Comment: Can you expand on this? It's a bit light on details and sounds more like a comment. Can you recall episode details?